# Python bottleneck argpartsort performance

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Is there a reason (considering that I didn't messed up on something) as to why bottleneck.argpartsort has its best performance when sorting the first n = 1000 elements in a given array?

I've created the following script:

```
d = numpy.random.rand(300000)
l = []
for i in range(5):
    to = time()
    ind = argpartsort(-d, pow(10,i))
    tf = time()
    l.append((pow(10,i), tf - to))
```

Which resulted in:

```
 [(1, 0.008157968521118164),
 (10, 0.006367921829223633),
 (100, 0.006164073944091797),
 (1000, 0.002994060516357422),
 (10000, 0.004293203353881836)]
```

Ploting the result gives:

[image: argpartsort performance]

I thought that the less values argpartsort had to track the faster it should be, but it was not what I've observed. Did I mess up somewhere or is it expected?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many times did you repeat the test? Perhaps some other processes were taking some of the CPU time at that time? Fluctuations at small scale are quite common.

Comment: Just now I saw your comment. I actually ran the test only for 3 times but I got the same result in all of them so I concluded the time consumed was a constant. Seeing your answer now I realized that's how the sorting algorithm works after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are only looking at 5 steps here. Here's how it looks when you do 500 steps:

[image]

I believe that this fluctuation comes from the [Hoare's quickselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) (the pivot selection is **the problem** - it might be very good but it might be very bad, quite random). Similar idea is used in quicksort so let's have a look:

```
d = numpy.random.rand(3000)

def test(n):
    ld = d[:n]
    s = time.time()
    ld.sort()
    e = time.time()
    return e-t
```

This code suggests that for increasing `i` the time spent on sorting should not go down (because we only take bigger slices of the same array, so if we can sort bigger slice faster then we should sort smaller slice at least as fast). Here's the result:

[image]

As you can see we have fluctuations here as well (and I'm not talking about big jumps which might be due to other stuff that my machine does but I'm talking about this tiny jumps between them). The problem lies in the algorithm itself. It is really fast only on average.

And finally note that everything your machine does in the meantime affects tests as well, so it is quite hard to give full diagnosis.